# Reading meta-data locks file

Tags: vb.net, jpeg, exif, ioexception

I have the following function to read the recording date of a .jpg-file:

```
 Public Shared Function GetRecordingDateOfPhoto(pathOfPhoto As String) As DateTime
            If Not IO.File.Exists(pathOfPhoto) Then
                Throw New FileNotFoundException
            End If
            Dim bitmapSource As BitmapSource = BitmapFrame.Create(New Uri(pathOfPhoto, UriKind.Relative))
            Dim bitmapMetadata As BitmapMetadata = TryCast(bitmapSource.Metadata, BitmapMetadata)
            Dim result As DateTime
            If DateTime.TryParse(bitmapMetadata.DateTaken, result) Then
                Return result
            Else
                Throw New FormatException
            End If
        End Function
```

This function returns the correct date, but when I do something like this

```
dim dateOfPhoto as Date = GetRecordingDateOfPhoto("foo.jpg")
My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile("foo.jpg", "bar.jpg")
```

then I get an exception from MoveFile(...): IOException ("The Process Cannot Access the File Because It Is Being Used by Another Process")

What do I have to change exactly (maybe using/end using?) in the GetRecordingDateOfPhoto(...)-function to avoid this exception?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this class is just terribly implemented. Blame Microsoft. BitmapFrame.Create internally creates a stream and never closes it.

source: [microsoft .net reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Imaging/BitmapFrame.cs)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the function is Shared. Its local variables exist only once regardless of how many class instantiations there are. Try making it not shared or set your variables to Nothing.